# Html5 canvas wont iterate using javascript in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, canvas

In a rails project I have microposts model:

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :avatar

  belongs_to :user
  mount_uploader :avatar, ImageUploader
```

I have created a _feed_item.html.erb partial:

```
<li id="<%= feed_item.id %>">
  <%= link_to gravatar_for(feed_item.user), feed_item.user %>
    <span class="user">
        <%= link_to feed_item.user.name, feed_item.user %>
    </span>
    <div id="content"><%= feed_item.content %></div>  
    <div id="id"><%= feed_item.id %></div>   
      <img hidden id="avatar" src=<%= feed_item.avatar_url(:thumb).to_s %> alt="Avatar">

    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="300" style="border:1px ">
    </canvas>  
    <script>
    (function myFunction() {
    var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById("avatar");
    ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);
    ctx.font = "20px Arial";
    var text = document.getElementById("content").innerHTML;
    ctx.fillText(text,20,50);
    })();
    </script>

    <span class="timestamp">
        Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(feed_item.created_at) %> ago.
    </span>
  <% if current_user?(feed_item.user) %>
    <%= link_to "delete", feed_item, method: :delete,
                                     data: { confirm: "You sure?" },
                                     title: feed_item.content %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

and a _feed.html.erb to display all microposts of a user:

```
<% if @feed_items.any? %>
  <ol class="microposts">
    <%= render partial: 'shared/feed_item', collection: @feed_items %>
  </ol>
  <%= will_paginate @feed_items %>
<% end %>
```

The problem is that everything works for the first micropost where everything is displayed as they should with the picture and the overlay text in the canvas. The rest of the microposts also have a canvas element but nothing is drawn inside. Can this be something I haven't addressed regarding passing information from rails to javascript correctly? Any other ideas?

Comment: You have multiple elements with the same id and `document.getElementById` is returning the first one.

Comment: If this is the case then all microposts should have the same picture and text, correct? But instead there is no picture or text. Thanks

Comment: It's returning the *first* element with the given id, not all elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this pattern

```
<li id="<%= feed_item.id %>" class="feed">
  <%= link_to gravatar_for(feed_item.user), feed_item.user %>
    <span class="user">
        <%= link_to feed_item.user.name, feed_item.user %>
    </span>
    <div class="content"><%= feed_item.content %></div>  
    <div id="id"><%= feed_item.id %></div>   
      <img hidden class="avatar" src=<%= feed_item.avatar_url(:thumb).to_s %> alt="Avatar">

    <canvas class="myCanvas" width="400" height="300" style="border:1px ">
    </canvas>

    <span class="timestamp">
        Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(feed_item.created_at) %> ago.
    </span>
  <% if current_user?(feed_item.user) %>
    <%= link_to "delete", feed_item, method: :delete,
                                     data: { confirm: "You sure?" },
                                     title: feed_item.content %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

--------- move this code out side _feed_item.html.erb partial -----------

```
<script>
(function myFunction() {
var feeds = $('.feed')
feeds.each(function() {
  var c = $(this).find(".myCanvas");
  var ctx = c[0].getContext("2d");
  var img = $(this).find(".avatar");
  ctx.drawImage(img[0], 10, 10);
  ctx.font = "20px Arial";
  var text = $(this).find(".content").html();
  ctx.fillText(text,20,50);
})
})();
</script>
```

Comment: Did that and got a:
TypeError: feed.getElementsByClassName is not a function
in the firefox console. Tried to resolve it but didn't work.
Thanks anyway

Comment: I have updated the js with jquery. Check if it work now.

Comment: I had to make some additions since I put the script in a new js file but it worked:

    $(function(){(function myFunction() {

    var feeds = $('.feed')

    feeds.each(function() {

    var c = $(this).find(".myCanvas");

    var ctx = c[0].getContext("2d");

    var img = $(this).find(".avatar");

    ctx.drawImage(img[0], 10, 10);

    ctx.font = "20px Arial";

    var text = $(this).find(".content").html();

    ctx.fillText(text,20,50);

    })

    })();});